# Biztalk 2009: Redirect a message to a different web service

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

Current State: BizTalk receive message via Web Service A (hosted on the same machine). BizTalk process the message and send it to backend.

Future State: BizTalk still receive message via Web Service A. If a field inside the message matches a certain value, BizTalk needs to send the message to a different web service (Web Service) on another server. Else, proceed with existing flow.

BizTalk is required as a middleware between Application and Web Service B due to network connection. Server for Web Service B only accept TLS1.2 which Application Server yet to support.

Is it possible to reroute the message even before it enter the first orchestration?

Kindly provide best way to do it with detail guidance on changes required or point to existing question or documentation if any.

p/s: Newbie to BizTalk. Let me know if further information need to be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, quite possible

1. Promote the field that you wish to route on in the schema
2. Set the filter expressions on the send ports that look at this promoted property

Note: For TLS 1.2 you will need a Custom End Point behaviour on the send port to specify to use TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dijkgraaf says, you can use Promote field on the schema and then use filter expressions on the send ports to redirect the incoming message to the new Web Service B.

If you need an Orchestration to implement some process before send to the Web Service B, you can use Filter Expression property of the first Receive Shape, to catch the messages with the Promoted Property value that you need.

[image]